# Equation of a straight line in spherical coordinates

Tags: analytic-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

I'm trying to prove the angle sum formula for a triangle on the surface of a sphere. In order to do this I wanted to create a general triangle on the sphere, with one vertex at $\theta = 0$  and one side along the angle $\phi = 0$ for simplicity. (I think this can be done without loss of generality?)

In order to do this I need to be able to express one of the other sides as a straight line in spherical coordinates. Intuition tells me that it is probably just $\theta = k\phi + \alpha$ and $\phi$ as a free parameter. I've tried proving this to myself by showing the the resulting curve is a great circle. I then tried to compute a path integral around this curve so I could check that it is equal to the circumference of my general sphere, however wolfram alpha tells me that I must upgrade to pro to get more computation time to do my integral. ($\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{k^2 + \sin{(kt + \alpha)}}$ dt)

I've also tried to show that in cartesian coordinates that any points resulting from this parameterization must be coplanar. I have had little success with this approach.

Am I completely wrong here? Is there some good way to see whether or not this is true?

Comment: I may not be understanding what you're asking, but the sides of a triangle in the surface of a sphere cannot be straight lines.  Or are you using the "flat" triangle with the same vertices as the "curved" triangle to demonstrate the inequality?

Comment: By "angle sum formula", do you mean something equivalent to the theorem that the sum of the interior angles (of a spherical triangle) minus $\pi$ is the area of the triangle divided by the radius (of the sphere) squared?

Comment: Hey, by straight lines I mean segments of great circles. Also, by angle sum formula I mean $ \sum_{vertices}(\mbox{interior angles}) = \pi + \frac{A}{a^2}$ where a is the radius of the sphere in question and A is the area of the triangle.

Comment: So that's "yes". :) Is there a reason you want a proof other than the standard [geometric argument using lunes](http://www.uwosh.edu/faculty_staff/szydliks/elliptic/elliptic.htm)?

Comment: I'm working through "Gravity" by James B. Hartle and it's one of the questions. Also, I was unaware of the standard geometrical argument using lunes so I will look into that now!

Comment: Perhaps the lunes argument obviates your question, but in case it's helpful: A great circle on the unit sphere $S$ is the intersection of $S$ and a plane $P$ through the origin. To get an equation in spherical coordinates, pick a unit vector $(a, b, c)$ normal to $P$, and write $ax + by + cz = 0$, replacing $(x, y, z)$ by their spherical coordinates expressions. (There are multiple conventions; not sure which you're using.) The result is a linear relation between circular trig functions of angles (rather than between angles themselves) and probably not pleasant for your purposes.

Comment: Could be interesting http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Motivation_for_tangent_space#The_line (with a picture!)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you assumed the $r$-coordinate of your path is constant.
Since you're looking for a path on the surface of a sphere, that's appropriate.

When you're trying to describe an object in a coordinate system, it helps to have very clear notions about the properties of that object as expressed in
that coordinate system.
There are a few important facts to keep in mind about a great circle.
One is that every point on the great circle is exactly opposite another
point on the great circle, that is, if $(r,\phi,\theta)$ is on the
great circle then so is $(r,\pi-\phi,\theta + pi)$.

Another fact is that as you travel around the great circle, after you cross
a "line of latitude" going "upward", you must later cross that same
line of latitude at a different point while going "downward".

A third fact is that unless the great circle happens to be a
"line of longitude", it will not pass through the poles. That is,
each great circle has a minimum latitude angle $\phi_0$ and a maximum
latitude angle (which by the first fact above must be $\pi - \phi_0$),
where $0 < \phi_0 < \pi/2$.
The great circle only attains its minimum latitude at one point; likewise the maximum latitude.

So if you have an equation of a great circle in the form
$$f(\phi, \theta) = 0,$$
this equation must have exactly one solution with $\phi = \phi_0$
and one with $\phi = \pi - \phi_0$;
but for each $\phi$ such that $\phi_0 < \phi_0 < \pi - \phi_0$,
there must be exactly *two* solutions of the equation.

On further examination of a great circle drawn on a sphere,
it should be obvious that at the point on the great circle where $\phi = \phi_0$, the circle is tangent to a line of latitude,
and at that point $\frac{d}{d\theta}\phi = 0$.

Your proposed equation, $\theta = k\phi + \alpha$,
is equivalent to $\theta - k\phi - \alpha = 0$.
Now we can see several flaws.
First, there is nothing in this equation to require that $\phi$ have
a maximum or minimum value anywhere except possibly at $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi$.
Second, there is only one solution to the equation for any given $\phi$.
(There should be two solutions for most values of $\phi$.)
Third, there is no point at which $\frac{d}{d\theta}\phi = 0$.

Let's try a different approach. The great circle is the intersection of
the surface of the sphere and a plane through the center of the sphere.
The equation of that plane is
$$ax + by + cz = 0.$$

Now convert the Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates:
\begin{align}
x &= r \sin \phi \cos \theta, \\
y &= r \sin \phi \sin \theta, \\
z &= r \cos \phi.
\end{align}

Making these substitutions directly into the equation of the plane, we have
$$ar \sin \phi \cos \theta + br \sin \phi \sin \theta + cr \cos \phi = 0.$$

Take out the factor of $r$ and combine some terms and we have
$$(a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta)\sin \phi + c \cos \phi = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think i have finally found how to go about this: Any circle on the surface of the circle must satisfy two equations. 1) $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r_0^2$ and 2) $ax + by + cz = d$ (The equation of a plane). Thus, converting to spherical coordinates, we have that $r = r_0$ and $a r sin(\phi)cos(\theta) + b r sin(\phi) sin(\theta) + c cos(\phi) = d$. You can then take the $sin(\phi)$ common to get $sin(\phi)(acos(\theta) + bsin(\theta))$ and multiply and divide by $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ to enable you to have that portion in the form $sin(\theta + \theta_0)$. Now you can see that a parametric equation can be given in a form $(r, \theta, \phi) = (1, sin^{-1}( \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} (\frac{(d - c cos(\phi)}{sin(\phi)})) - \theta_0, u), u = 0...2π$.

What do you think?

Answer (score -1):

To create a line in circular coordinates, you can just do it like this: $sin(\theta) = m cos(\theta) + c/r$, where $m$ is the gradient and $c$ is the y-intercept. This comes from the $y = mx + c$ definition.

The $y = mx$ part is straightforward, but it is not as obvious. To see how this works explicitly, consider that to your base equation $sin(\theta) = m cos(\theta)$, you are adding the equation for a horizontal line: $sin(\theta) = c/r$ which comes straight from geometry.

You can use similar principles to extend this to spherical coordinates.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a straight line in flat cartestian space. It's more like I'm trying to find the equation for a geodesic connecting two points on the surface of a sphere in the non-Euclidean geometry of the surface of the sphere ie. the great circle connecting two points on the surface.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Let me try to come up with that equation.

Comment: I've been thinking about this and I'm pretty sure that the answer has to be $\theta = a\sin(k\phi + c) + d$. All great circles are either circles of constant $\phi$ or $\theta$ will not loop around fully and have a maximum and minimum value less than 2$\pi$. What do people think?

Comment: I tried your solution, and while it does yield some circles, it does not work for most values of a,c,d.

Comment: I am trying deriving it myself, and am getting a similar result. The sin comes from converting an angle to a length along the diameter. I am trying to come with a more specific result as this is not true for all a,c,d.

Comment: I am wondering also whether this solution is sufficient to yield all possible circles. I am having difficulty creating circles to my will.